# How can I use the Windows 10 theme for my forms in Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Is it possible to use Windows 10 theme for forms in Visual Studio? None of the `FormBorderStyle` options seem to be the correct theme. Is there any other way to get this theme?

Comment: have you tried debugging the form?  The designer has an older theme it seems but when you run the app it uses the windows 10 version.

Comment: Looks like that was it. I wonder why they haven't updated the themes in the designer.

Answer (score 0):

This could be a bug, or something that needs to be optimized.
It is recommended that you post the problem on [Visual Studio Developer Community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/VisualStudio).